# how to send an alert message with special letters in different languages

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsf

I am programming a Web-Application with Java EE and JSF.

I want to give alert (javascript) messages with letters (such as Ç,ü and ö etc.) on my app. But, after an alert function is fired, I see an alert message with unrelated characters such as , instead of special letters on .xhtml pages on any browser (I tried it on IE10 and Chrome).

I need an advice to handle the problem. If I find a solution, I can also use it to set values of element (ex./h:commandButton) by javascript.

EDIT:

Additional information - Static strings that includes special letters on html or jsf tags are shown properly. However, when I change them via some javascript functions, if there is any special letters in strings that are altered, these letters cannot be shown properly. Using meta in head part of html for utf8 or configuring head part with response attribute of servlet does not change anything!

All feedback appreciated!

Comment: not really a solution for you but I had a similar problem eventually just used the growl component provided by primefaces. Are you stuck using javascript for the alert ?

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/6WZpe/

Comment: @Aidan , I updated the link - http://jsfiddle.net/sean35/6WZpe/6/. The point is that when I write letters on .xhtml, I see all in right form. However, when I send an alert message with these letters, I see <?> or any different inrelated characters based on a browser.

Comment: @KennethClark, no, i am not stuck on using javascript alert message. Which functions or tags can I use in primefaces for this operation? and if there is any library or any different things I have to add to use primefaces?

Comment: primefaces is pretty straight forward as long as you are jsf2, simply add the primefaces jar, take a look at the demo .. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/growl.jsf

Comment: @KennethClark, I tried p:growl after your advice and I think it is useful. Have you ever change colors of the growl or font of characters?

Comment: I have not but ill check this out .. http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-customize-growl-primefaces